# Can't use user with MANAGER role to create user from angular UI

Tags: spring-security, jhipster

I'm trying to add MANAGER role. User with MANAGER must be able to create other users.

I've update AuthoritiesConstants.java like below :

```
public final class AuthoritiesConstants {

    public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

    public static final String USER = "ROLE_USER";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
    public static final String MANAGER = "ROLE_MANAGER";

    private AuthoritiesConstants() {
    }
}
```

I've also update authorities.csv:

```
name
ROLE_ADMIN
ROLE_USER
ROLE_MANAGER
```

I've try to update the UserResource.java like this :

```
@PostMapping("/users")
    @Timed
    @Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN,AuthoritiesConstants.MANAGER})
    public ResponseEntity createUser(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save User : {}", managedUserVM);

    }
```

and this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class UserResource {
    @PostMapping("/users")
        @Timed
        @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_MANAGER')")
        public ResponseEntity createUser(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserVM managedUserVM) throws URISyntaxException {
            log.debug("REST request to save User : {}", managedUserVM);
           //....

        }
//....
}
```

I've logged in the angular UI and create a user **toto** with ROLE_MANAGER and ROLE_USER roles. I've update html file so that user with ROLE_MANAGER have access to user management pages.

When the user toto submit user creation form, the backend responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: I'm using the angular UI. For the manager role, I've added     public static final String MANAGER = "ROLE_MANAGER"; to AuthoritiesConstants and ROLE_MANAGER to authorities.csv

Comment: I'm logged with a user having ROLE_MANAGER role . No, I don't change anything in SecurityConifguration.

Comment: As admin , I've created a new user in the angular UI and give this role to him.  FYI, the directive *jhiHasAnyAuthority="['ROLE_MANAGER']" works fine.

Comment: Sorry I give up, it takes too much time to get details and this happened with all your questions which are always missing basic details.

Comment: Ok. I'll edit the question with all the modification I've done and what I was intended to do.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I've update the question. Is it have all the details now ?

Comment: I answered but the most important detail was missing: for which request URL did you get the 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your problem and got an access denied error but in the browser console it was for `/api/users/authorities`.

So the fix consists in authorizing `ROLE_MANAGER` role to access `UserResource.getAuthorities()`:

```
@GetMapping("/users/authorities")
@Timed
@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.MANAGER})
public List<String> getAuthorities() {
    return userService.getAuthorities();
}
```

Comment: You are right. It is the issue. Thanks for the support.